# Remove lines contain pattern exclude another pattern bash

Tags: bash

I have a file

```
$ cat File
ce5 xxx 123
ed9 myself,yyy,fail? -
f27 xxx,fail? 145
105 yyy,fail? -
```

I want to remove all the lines containing string ",fail?" but not "myself" in bash.

Expected output

```
$ cat File
ce5 xxx 123
ed9 myself,yyy,fail? -
```

I can grep the lines but not sure how to remove them

```
cat File | grep -v "myself" | grep ",fail?"
f27 xxx,fail? 145
105 yyy,fail? -
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do such things (easily) with grep.

Print `mysql` and don't print `,fail?` with `sed`:

```
sed '/myself/n; /,fail\?/d' File
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '! /,fail\?/ || /myself/'
```